# Using paste with " and \

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `paste` with some " and \, but can't seem to get the character string correct.

Desired output:

`echo -n "\end{document}"`

Using `paste`:

```
paste0("echo -n \"'\end{document}\'")
```

But I get:

> Error: '\e' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""echo -n \"'\e"

Comment: you also need to escape the escape `paste0('echo -n "\\end{document}"'); cat('echo -n "\\end{document}"')`